# CSS styles disappear after refresh in React

Tags: css, reactjs

CSS styles disappear after refresh in React app. my website was reactive while making changes and working. I clicked save and everything turned into the below screenshot. I didnt make any physical changes to any of my code when this happened and i have also tried to copy my code into another repository and start fresh and i get the same result. Can someone help me ?

-I have tried reinstalling prettier as suggested on stackoverflow that didnt work either

I have added my code below. [[current folder and screenshot of the current state of my site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYaaO.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yisZn.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.